# Google Apps Script - Two ways sync dynamically updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a huge sheet containing enumerated rows, each one containing data of a single film. I need to have another sheet listing the rows that have a column containing certain text, but I need these rows to be synced both ways, so that if a contributor changes something in one of the two sheets, it is reflected in the other. Also I need that if new rows meeting the same criteria are added, they should be reported in the other sheet dynamically as well. I know it should be doable with Apps Script but I have no idea where to start from.

Comment: Hi! Your question will get more attention when you lay out your shot at creating it and then asking for help in a specific part of the build. General questions like this tend to get downvoted, so it's closed. Google Apps Script will definitely get you there, but there's some grind to it at the beginning. :) Another approach would be to hire a freelancer to build it for you and have them explain how it works, so you can get your toe in a practical way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Two way sync for user edit of single cells only

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ['Sheet0','Sheet1'];//Sheet names
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx) {
    const rA1 = e.range.getA1Notation();
    const shts = names.map(name => e.source.getSheetByName(name));
    shts.filter(s => shts.indexOf(s) != idx).forEach(s => s.getRange(rA1).setValue(e.value));
  }
}
```